# __webpack_require__(...) is not a function when using ES5 module in ES6

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have a ReactJs component library that I build using Typescript + Webpack and target ES5. Here are the relevant sections of tsconfig, webpack.config.json files.

```
// Library files
// tsconfig.json
"target": "ES5",
"module": "commonjs",

// webpack.config.js

module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
```

I then reference it in another ReactJS package built that is compiled using TypeScript and targets ES6. Here are the relevant sections in tsconfig.json

```
// Consumer package files
//tsconfig.json
    "lib": ["es6", "DOM", "es5"],
    "module": "commonjs",

// webpack.config.js
// No resolve or rules entries
```

The build succeeds for both library and consumer package. But when I load the consumer package in browser I get following error in console.

I can not change the ReactJS component library that is using ES5, how can I use it in my Consumer library that is using ES6?

When I compile the ES5 library this is what I see in bundle.js file (I have compiled in development mode for readibility.

```
exports.getQuestionsFromS3 = getQuestionsFromS3;
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: sample_module_name.getQuestionsFromS3 is not a function
    at Object../app/index.tsx (index.tsx:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:848)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.0 (app.chunk.js:2887)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:848)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at app.chunk.js:1
```

Comment: You're probably importing it wrong

Comment: I don't think it's a problem since webpack will accept `csj`, `esm` modules to create harmony module which can run on browser unless there is something wrong with your code?

Comment: Thanks ... I am importing is using

```
import { functionName } from "package-name";
```

Comment: How can I debug and narrow down the issue?

Comment: Can you also share your code which caused the error?